# Get a new column with updated values, where each row change in time depending on the actual column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that includes as columns an ID, Date and Place denoted by a number. I need to simulate a real time update where I create a new column that says how many different places are at the moment, so each time a new place appear in the column, the new column change it's value and shows it.

This is just a little piece of the original table with hundreds of millions of rows.

Here is an example, the left table is the original one and the right table is what I need.

[image]

I tried to do it with this piece of code but I cannot use the function DISTINCT with the `OVER` clause.

```
    SELECT ID, Dates, Place,
    count (distinct(Place)) OVER (PARTITION BY Place ORDER BY Dates) AS 
    DiffPlaces
    FROM #informacion_prendaria_muestra
    order by ID;
```

Comment: Please don't use images or links to images. Instead add the data as text.

Comment: FYI the editor has a code format button.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be possible by using `DENSE_RANK()` in SQL server

you can try this

```
SELECT ID, Dates, Place,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Place) AS 
DiffPlaces
FROM #informacion_prendaria_muestra
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a self join query like this - without using windows functions -:

```
select 
    t.ID, t.[Date], t.Place, 
    count(distinct tt.Place) diffPlace
from 
    yourTable t left join 
    yourTable tt on t.ID = tt.ID and t.[Date] >= tt.[Date]
group by 
    t.ID, t.[Date], t.Place
order by 
    Id, [Date];
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/71243)